# Video on splash screen not appearing Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, boot, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying to have a short 20 second video play in place of the log output when my raspberry pi is turned on. I followed the directions here: http://blog.sheasilverman.com/2013/09/adding-a-startup-movie-to-your-raspberry-pi/ but my video does not appear at all. I have the raspberry pi 3 running Raspbian (jessie) and cannot find an updated way of doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If all you wish to do is to play a video on boot please open up /etc/rc.local using the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Then on the line just above the one that says exit 0 Enter the following line:

```
omxplayer /path/mohammad/is/awesome.mp4 &
```

Be sure to replace the file path with your actual file path. Furthermore if you wish to have the video loop please use the line below instead of the one above.

```
omxplayer --loop /path/mohammad/is/awesome.mp4 &
```

After making the desired edits to the file please save and close the file then reboot your pi to see the changes take effect.

Comment: `path/mohammad/is/awesome` :)

Comment: @sir_ian good to know someone appreciates my creative genius.